# NullPointerException using liferay-ui taglib

Tags: liferay, taglib, liferay-6

I'm trying to use the liferay-ui:icon-help tag in my (Liferay 6.1) portlet, but adding

`<liferay-ui:icon-help message="help me"/>`

to my edit.jsp gives me

`ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.NullPointerException at com.liferay.taglib.ui.IconHelpTag.processEndTag(IconHelpTag.java:57)`

I'm sure I imported the taglib correctly because other tags such as liferay-ui:calendar work just fine.

Did I forget anything?

edit: IconHelpTag.java:57 suggests that there's something wrong involving the theme, but I did not play around with that, the server is pretty much as it came out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the liferay-ui:icon-help tag makes call to a theme related object, add the following lines to your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there anywhere I would find such a thing in the future? It took me ages to even find the correct tag to do this, not to mention the correct import and now this.

Comment: Try it , break it, fix it , learn it the hard way. The documentation is really poor so just try things out and ask arround.

Comment: I agree with Dvd Prd's advice. In addition to it I would also check the Liferay Source code because it will tell you the reason it's throwing errors, and you can see the conditions that lead to it being thrown.