# Liferay error using primefaces: NullPointerException when using tag "<liferay-ui:journal-article>"

Tags: primefaces, liferay, liferay-6

Short introduction to my environment: I use Liferay 6.2, building a portlet with Maven and using Primefaces 4.0. Previously I was using Liferay 6.1 with plain JSP/AUI and I was having no issues with the above mentioned tag.

As soon as I include the `<liferay-ui:journal-article>` tag into my XHTML page that previously worked, it will straight away run into an exception that looks very weird and scares me a lot!

```
Resource handler=[com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ResourceHandlerOuterImpl@3caf23f] was unable to create a resource for resourceName=[journal-article.xhtml] libraryName=[liferay-ui] contentType=[null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter url is null
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:314)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.isFaceletCached(DefaultFaceletCache.java:126)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.needsToBeRefreshed(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getComponentMetadata(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:237)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:937)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:605)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.createComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:161)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:486)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:169)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:320)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:379)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:358)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:914)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:227)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:85)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:112)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
....
```

Some notes on things I tried up to now:
I checked the other articles on stack overflow that sounded similar ([NullPointerException using liferay-ui taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811498/nullpointerexception-using-liferay-ui-taglib)) and I messed around with my Web.xml and POM.xml, since many articles on the internet suggested incomplete/broken JSF configurations. 
In the process I found some even more scary articles on the web that indicated a broken library or filter configuration for the faces environment. But non of this really changed my reality.

Any ideas what I could try besides switching away from primefaces to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can not use liferay's custom tags in xhtml view file of primefaces portlet.

As a workaround, you can fetch web content(journal article) using liferay api in init method of your view scoped jsf bean and set some bean variable with content. Then in your xhtml view you can show that bean variable.

Hope this would help you.